# Need Guidance Setting Up Debian File Server

Tags: debian, media, samba, nfs, fileserver

I've recently gotten really into Linux, and am interested in setting up a file server in my home. I want to be able to ssh from outside of my network. The file server would be used mostly for media, eventually I want to be able to set up a little raspberry pi chip to stream the media on my server to my tv via hdmi(but this is a future endeavor).

I also want the files to be available to windows, other linux distros, and other UNIX OS's. How hard would this be to accomplish? Are there any basic guides? After researching it a bit I keep coming across NFS and Samba servers, which would be more appropriate for my setup(if any at all).

I understand this question is somewhat vague, but I'm hoping one of you guys is pretty experienced with this and can nudge me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up my file server using this tutorial http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-linux-file-server-using-samba  a using ubuntu server lts. It was pretty easy to follow and runs perfectly well on a 10 year or older computer. Using samba to set up your windows shares was covered pretty well in this tutorial. No gui with ubuntu server, this will get you really into the linux file system and hand editing config files. It was a great learning experience for me!!

Comment: Cool, I'll do this(however on debian, which should be almost exactly the same). No gui at all? Like the entire thing is done from the terminal? Sounds fine to me, just kinda weird that there isn't a windows manager.

Thanks :)

Comment: you of course can add a gui if you wish, but if you are trying to learn linux command line, this will be the best for you. In gui you are able to install gui sama editors which is fine if you want, but this will be a better learning experience. Be sure to download the Manual for the edition of server that you download, it will have more detailed instructions for setting up your samba service. Just a note, this tutorial specifically uses Ubuntu Server, alot of what you learn with this will transfer to other linux distros but some of the commands may be different.

Comment: I don't use the gui because my system is very limited: 256mb ram with an old amd XP athalon 2600. ;-)

Comment: Alright cool, ya I'm fine doing it without the gui. I think things from ubuntu will transfer fine to debian(since ubuntu came from debian), however if not it won't be hard to look up.


Thanks for the tips :)